# Xcode 13 unable to auto-upload dSYM Firebase scripts

Tags: xcode, firebase, crashlytics, dsym

Our app has been using the `upload-symbols` script in a build phase to auto-upload dSYM files to Crashlytics for a while now.

However, since updating to Xcode 13, all of our archives have been failing due to that script -

```
[...] /Script-EF456CDC25C0F14E00D10098.sh: line 5: 47180 Killed: 9               "${PODS_ROOT}/FirebaseCrashlytics/upload-symbols" -gsp <path-to-plist> -p ios "${DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH}/${DWARF_DSYM_FILE_NAME}"
```

Does anyone have any ideas on what's wrong?

Couple details:

- comes last in build phases
- has both `${DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH}/${DWARF_DSYM_FILE_NAME}/Contents/Resources/DWARF/${TARGET_NAME}` and `$(SRCROOT)/$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/$(INFOPLIST_PATH)` listed under input files
- all other build phase parameters are default